# Video doesn't play in VLCJ

Tags: java, swing, vlcj

I made this aplication on Eclipse for a school project. It's just suppose to run a video when a button is press. In the IDE everything works fine, althought an error occures but doesn't cause any trouble (Will leave it, thought, so if it causes something I want to now.)
Now, when I export the Jar file and try to run it, in the same computer, video doesn't play. What can I do?

```
JFrame vid = new JFrame();
        vid.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        vid.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        vid.setVisible(true);

        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(c);
        vid.add(p);

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),"C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
        MediaPlayerFactory mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        EmbeddedMediaPlayer emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(vid));
        emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(c));
        emp.toggleFullScreen();
        emp.setEnableMouseInputHandling(false);
        emp.setEnableKeyInputHandling(false);
        String file="/resources/sky.mp4";
        emp.prepareMedia(file);
        emp.play();
```

Here is the error code that appears:

```
[0000000017a2b420] core vout display error: Failed to set on top
```

Please, help me, as I need the project to work.

Comment: Is `/resources/sky.mp4` contained within the Jar file or on disk?  If it's in the Jar file, it won't be playable, as it's an entry in a Zip file, not a file on the disk, you'll either need to extract it or use `Class#getResource` to get an `URL` reference which `VLCj` might be able to play

Comment: Could I make a folder to extract the Jar and put the file in there so the program plays it?

Comment: In theory, yes. You have to allow for the fact that you may not have permissions to write the file and choose a location which is likely to provide you with access (like the users home directory)

Comment: Note that the Java-FX `MediaPlayer` can handle videos in a Jar. From the [`Media`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media(java.lang.String)) docs. *".. HTTP, FILE, and JAR URIs are supported."*

Comment: I could put it on the Public Folder so the file and path may be the same. It is not for private use but in school, so I guess the security is not need as all users are public.

Comment: Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got to work it around a bit. 
As I can't use a URL instead of String, and String doesn't let me do a Class#getResource, I finally decide to run it from a public folder which should not change, in theory, from pc to pc.

So my code end up being:

```
String file = new File("C:/Users/Public/Videos/sky.mp4").getAbsolutePath();
        emp.prepareMedia(file);
        emp.play();
```

While not ideal to pass without guidance, as we will be installing the program, it does the job.

Comment: <cough>macs<cough>

Comment: @MadProgrammer School only has Windows, so, no prob there.